# Linear and convex independence of "probability vectors"

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-hulls, linear-independence

We have vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ with $n \leq m$. Each $v_i$ is a "probability vector" in the sense that its entries are all non-negative, and sum to one.

Suppose that $\{v_i\}$ is linearly dependent. Does it follow that some $v_i$ is a *convex* combination of the other vectors?

I think I can get some sort of geometric intuition going for this but have no idea how to settle whether it's true in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider in $\Bbb R^4$ the following four (column) vectors:

$$[v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4]=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&\frac12&0\\ 0&1&0&\frac12\\ 0&0 &\frac12&\frac12\\ 0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

They are linearly dependent. Notice that any three of them are linearly independent, which means that for any permutation $(i,j,k,l)$ of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ there is exactly one way to write the vector $v_i$ as a linear combination $v_i=\alpha_{ij}v_j+\alpha_{ik}v_k+\alpha_{il}v_l$ of the other three. Your claim would be that there is some $i$ such that $\alpha_{ij}+\alpha_{ik}+\alpha_{il}=1$ and $\alpha_{ij},\alpha_{ik},\alpha_{il}\ge0$. This is easily disproved by inspection \begin{align}v_1&=v_2+2v_3-2v_4\\ v_2&=v_1-2v_3+2v_4\\ v_3&=\frac12v_1-\frac12v_2+v_4\\ v_4&=-\frac12v_1+\frac12v_2+v_3\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily: $v_1,\cdots,v_m$ can be the vertices of a convex polytope. Try $N=m=3$ to envision this possibility.

Comment: The intersection of a vector subspace $V$ with an affine subspace $H$ that does not contain the origin satifies $\dim (V\cap H)\le \dim V-1$, so you want at least $n=4$: otherwise, $v_1,v_2,v_3$ will lie on a line, an therefore at least one of them will be convex combination of the other two. Not so if $v_1,\cdots, v_4$ are the vertices of a square...

Comment: Thanks, this is the intuition that misled me!